# Access raw retrofit data from server pre GsonConverter

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

How does one access the raw "string" of data received from the server before it is processed by the GsonConveterFactory?

This is for an Android project using Kotlin

Thanks

Comment: you could perhaps try to add an http interceptor for this, perhaps this can provide you with the raw response but i'm not 100% sure on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using an [OkHttp interceptor](https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/interceptors/).